# how to pass a complex chain as an argument to a batch 'index1','index2','index3'

Tags: string, parameters, batch-file, arguments

I want to pass this string  `'index1','index2','index3'` to a batch

```
test2.cmd 1 'index1','index2','index3' 3
```

and if test2.cmd is

```
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
```

I'd like to see

```
echo 1
echo 'index1','index2','index3'
echo 3
```

But it does not work... cause I see

```
echo 1
echo'index1'
echo 'index2'
```

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 3):

Just enclose the string in double quotes:

```
test2.cmd 1 "'index1','index2','index3'" 3
```

Edit to answer your comment:

Also change test2.cmd to

```
echo %1
echo %~2
echo %3
```

Comment: but the "" will be passed to the cmd? I don't want :( 
Actually, my problem is more complex. LEt me try to explain it to you.

First I have a vba program running and calculating that string 'index1,'index2','index3' then it passes the argument to a batch file . Then this batch file call sqlplus and passes this argument to a .sql file which then do 

DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE col IN (&6) 
&6 must be 'index1','index2,'index3' .

Comment: OK, in that case you need to change your test2.cmd to use %~2 instead of %2. That removes surrounding quotes.

Comment: Does it make sense to do that ? 
"%~INDEXES"  avec INDEXES = 'index1','index2'

Cause if I do this  code VBA  index = Chr(34) & 'index1-index2' & Chr(34)  , an exception is thrown and it launches then microsoft visual studio debugger which I am not familiar with.
Thx for help

Comment: Obvisouly it does not work "%~INDEXES" . I don't know how to manager to pass the "" around my chain... An exception is launched from launch_insertPLS.Exe ouch

Comment: Here is what I do but there is problem then cause the script does not go on.

 INDEXES  =  "'index1','index2','index3','index4'"
 sqlplus .... %~INDEXES%

I really don't succeed to pass that string (

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here that "," is a delim for parameters, so you have to replace it, or quote the complete parameter like Vicky advised.

You got more problems if index1,index2,.. can contain quotes, then the parameter will be broken.